# .htaccess url rewrite with ssl redirection

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble combining a url query parameter rewrite (fancy-url) with a .htaccess ssl redirection.

My .htaccess file is currently:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
ServerSignature Off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# in https: process secure.html in https
RewriteCond %{server_port} =443
RewriteCond $1 ^secure$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+).html$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

# in https: force all other pages to http
RewriteCond %{server_port} =443
RewriteCond $1 !^secure$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+).html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,N]

# in http: force secure.html to https
RewriteCond %{server_port} !=443
RewriteCond $1 ^secure$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+).html$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,N]

# in http: process other pages as http
RewriteCond %{server_port} !=443
RewriteCond $1 !^secure$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+).html$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The fancy-url rewriting is working fine but the redirection to/from https isn't working at all.

If I replace the 2 lines containing

```
RewriteRule ^(.+).html$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,N]
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^(.+).html$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

then the https redirection works fine but the fancy-url rewriting doesn't work.

Is it possible to combine these two?

***Edit:***

The desired results are:

```
1. http://domain.com/secure.html is rewritten to https://domain.com/index.php?page=secure
2. http://domain.com/foo.html is rewritten to http://domain.com/index.php?page=foo
3. https://domain.com/secure.html is rewritten to https://domain.com/index.php?page=secure
4. https://domain.com/foo.html is rewritten to http://domain.com/index.php?page=foo
```

(I had to put them in a code block as more than 1 link is not allowed for new users)

So secure.html is always https while foo.html (all other pages) are always http.

***Solution:***

Thanks to Gumbo, the solution is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
ServerSignature Off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# in https: force all other pages to http
RewriteCond %{server_port} =443
RewriteCond $1 !^secure$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,N]

# in http: force secure.html to https
RewriteCond %{server_port} !=443
RewriteCond $1 ^secure$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,N]

# in https: process secure.html in https
RewriteCond %{server_port} =443
RewriteCond $1 ^secure$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

# in http: process other pages as http
RewriteCond %{server_port} !=443
RewriteCond $1 !^secure$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you’ve expected to happen and what actually happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put those rule, that cause an external redirect, before those rules, that just cause an internal redirect. So:

```
# in https: force all other pages to http
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond $1 !^secure$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]

# in http: force secure.html to https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond $1 ^secure$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]

# in https: process secure.html in https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond $1 ^secure$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

# in http: process other pages as http
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond $1 !^secure$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not the correct way to detect what the server port is, it should follow the same rules as http_host using `^443$` and `!^443` respectively. You really should capitalize server_port as well, it's good practice. Here is a [good little tutorial](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/ssl-example-usage-in-htaccess.html) that might help you out.

Comment: When I started the ^443$ method wasn't working on my server while the =443 method above was - I'll give it another go and confirm.

Comment: `=443` and `^443$` are semantically identical. The former is just a lexicographical (equality) comparison while the latter is a regular expression comparison.